# Sporadic core dumps (Segmentation faults, Illegal Instruction) using Tensorflow on CentOS 7

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow

I frequently get core dumps (Illegal instruction, Segmentation fault) when training models using tensorflow.  They are somewhat sporadic, but seem to increase in frequency as the model architecture gets more complex (more nodes, more layers).

I got the following set up:
CentOS 7
CUDA Tooklit Version 8
cuDNN version 5.1
tensorflow-gpu Version 1.0.0 installed by pip

All the environmental paths were set up and tensorflow seems to recognize and pick up both GPUs, CUDA and necessary libraries...

```
import tensorflow as tf  
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.8.0 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.8.0 locally
```

The first error occurred when I was trying to build a multi-layer deep network and would fail almost every time.  So I began from scratch and went to the tensorflow tutorials and tried simpler things which seemed to work.....but not always.

So, as a small experiment, I took two models of differing complexity from the tutorial on the MNIST data from tensorflows' website with slight modifications.  One is a simple softmax regression model, saved as `softmax.py` which looks like this:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
sess = tf.InteractiveSession(config=config)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
y = tf.matmul(x,W) + b
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
for _ in range(1000):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

The second file `multiconv.py` looks like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])


def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                    strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True

with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(20000):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
        if i % 100 == 0:
            train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
            print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
        train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
    print('test accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

If I run both of these programs 100 times

```
$cmd="python softmax.py"; for i in $(seq 100); do $cmd &>> temp.txt; sleep 1; done
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and

```
$cmd="python multiconv.py"; for i in $(seq 100); do $cmd &>> temp.txt; sleep 1; done
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So, the more complex the model, the more frequently it happens.

I believe I've already ruled out a memory issue as the underlying error, as I watch the memory output using the nvidia-smi command and it stays fairly constant.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 381.22                 Driver Version: 381.22                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 0000:02:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   52C    P2    61W / 250W |    413MiB / 11172MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 0000:81:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 27%   47C    P8    18W / 250W |    161MiB / 11172MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     31956    C   python                                         403MiB |
|    1     31956    C   python                                         151MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I've captured one of the errors using gdb and the out put was this

```
0x00007fff8d3fbb90 in ?? () from /lib64/libcuda.so.1
```

and I can provide the full traceback if needed.

Does anyone have any thoughts how I can begin to troubleshoot this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem had to deal with numpy.   Reinstalling numpy using pip over the version that was installed by the tensorflow-gpu pip package seemed to fix it.

EDIT: Further investigation leads me to believe it comes from a conflict installing scikit-learn after tensorflow.  The numpy versions cause conflicts.